# Fragments, ViewModel, FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android

estoy desarrollando mi app para final de curso, es una pokedex, el caso que quiero mostrar una activity con fragments que hagan swipe con informacion obtenida desde firebase, ese no es el problema, el problema es que quiero que cada fragment que yo cree al hacer swipe se muestre la informaicon del siguiente pokemon y al volver aparezca la informaicon que estaba, he estado investigando y se que es usando un ViewModel y FragmentPageAdapter, pero por mas que encuentro y leo info no me entero de bien, ¿Alguien podria darme un buen ejemplo de como realizar lo que necesito? no que sea exactamente igual o siemplemente una explicacion de como hacer que funcionen bien

Un saludo y gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción para realizar lo que comentaste es utilizar un viewpager. Lo bueno es que hace un tiempo google lanzó un mejor componente que se llama viewpager2. Tiene algunas mejores y a mi parecer es más fácil de utilizar, casi parecido a un adapter de un RecyclerView por no decir que es casi lo mismo, también se puede utilizar con fragments. Tendrías dos opciones

- Si lo utilizas como fragments, asegúrate que en el constructor de tu fragment le pases la data necesaria para que puedas mostrarla, por ejemplo el nombre del Pokemon y la ruta de la imagen [ No se que parámetros estes manejando así que esto es un ejemplo]. Luego mediante los argumentos del fragment obtienes esos valores y los pintas.
- Si lo utilizas como un adapter, de igualmanera, tendrías que pasar una lista de tus objetos y cada objetos debe tener la información necesaria para pintarla. Luego el adapter se encarga de pintar cada elemento el que le indiques, tal cual un adapter para un RecyclerView..

Aqui te dejo un repositorio que encontré con estos ejemplos.

Ejemplo -> https://github.com/dilpreet2028/ViewPager2

Bueno para ejemplo más avanzados, por si deseas investigar animaciones, resize, etc. te dejo los ejemplo de otro repositorio de GitHub.

Ejemplos avanzados -> https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: he mirado el proyecto y esta en kotlin, podrias pasarmelo pero en java? gracias de antemano, tambien la info que he encontrado me me decia que el metodo getItem del pageviewmodel, suelen hacer un switch con los fragments, en mi situacion es imposible, he intentado pasarle al view model un arraylist<Pokemon> (mi tipo de dato) y no hay manera

Comment: Puede ser que tu modelo no sea parcelable por eso no puedes pasarlo entre fragments. No entiendo porque el viewmodel no puede contener un arraylist de tipo Pokemon, en todo caso puedes revisar lo que es LiveData, te ayudara mucho para persistir objetos. Por último, encontré este repositorio con un ejemplo simple de viewpager2 -> https://github.com/Rajnish23/ViewPager2